# Non-perfect ideal $I$ such that $\mathrm{projdim}(R/I)<\infty$

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, homological-algebra, noetherian

Let $R$ be a Noetherian local ring. A proper ideal of $R$, $I$ is called perfect if grade$(R/I)=$projdim$(R/I)$ where grade$(R/I)=$depth$_IR$ and projdim$(R/I)$ is the projective dimension of $R/I$.

> Is there an example of a non-perfect ideal $I$ with
>   projdim$(R/I)<\infty$?

Fact : Since $I$ is not perfect, projdim$(R/I)>$grade$(R/I)$.

Comment: Over a regular local ring, all ideals have finite projective dimension. In $R = k[[x,y]]$, the ideal $x(x,y)$ will do the job.

Comment: Thank you very much for the helpful example!